# Partitions exist, but won't show in Linux / Windows file system

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, filesystems

**Background**:

I was using RAID1 configuration with two HDDs. It was set up using motherboard's (Asus x470 Prime Pro) RAID controller, which was working fine for Windows, but was not usable under Linux due to lack of drivers. As there was no way to "undo" RAID configuration from UEFI's built-in tool, I simply disabled RAID and moved one disks entire content to the left (since first few hundred MBs were occupied by RAID metadata). I was curious if simply moving actual disk data (with partitions tables, of course) could work, and well... it both did and did not.

**Problem**:

In both Linux (Debian) and Windows GUI disk partitions managers, when I check the HDD I modified, there is no sight of partitions whatsoever. They also do not appear in file system, obviously.
[image: Debian Disks utility]

Surprisingly, under Linux, some command line tools (like fdisk and gdisk) show partitions just fine.

fdisk:

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.36).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda1: 1.82 TiB, 2000381018112 bytes, 3906994176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Alignment offset: 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F7AE9EF0-19AC-4E53-B0F1-09179E8DFDAA

Device           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1p1         34      32767      32734    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda1p2      32768  419770367  419737600 200.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda1p3  419770368 2333446143 1913675776 912.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda1p4 2333446144 2490693631  157247488    75G Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Command (m for help): v

No errors detected.
Header version: 1.0
Using 4 out of 128 partitions.
A total of 1416300511 free sectors is available in 1 segment.
```

(I remember fdisk to print an error that there was no copy of GPT table written at the end of the disk, but it offered to repair it for me, which I did in hope that it will resolve the issue - it didn't, it just made this particular error to be not printed anymore.)

gdisk:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sda1: 3906994176 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): F7AE9EF0-19AC-4E53-B0F1-09179E8DFDAA
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3906994142
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 1416300511 sectors (675.3 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              34           32767   16.0 MiB    0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
   2           32768       419770367   200.1 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
   3       419770368      2333446143   912.5 GiB   0700  Basic data partition
   4      2333446144      2490693631   75.0 GiB    0700  Basic data partition

Command (? for help): v

Caution: Partition 1 doesn't begin on a 8-sector boundary. This may
result in degraded performance on some modern (2009 and later) hard disks.

Consult http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-4kb-sector-disks/
for information on disk alignment.

No problems found. 1416300511 free sectors (675.3 GiB) available in 1
segments, the largest of which is 1416300511 (675.3 GiB) in size.
```

The only command line tool that seems to have problems detecting partitions seems to be partprobe:

```
sudo partprobe -s
/dev/sda: msdos partitions 1
/dev/sdb: msdos partitions 1
/dev/nvme0n1: gpt partitions 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Obviously /dev/sda and /dev/sdb are my HDDs from previous RAID configuration, and /dev/sda was the HDD I mangled with.

If I understand correctly, the errors regarding partitions to "not start on physical sector boundary" that fdisk prints seem to be not really relevant, as this looks like just a performance issue (confirmed by gdisk output) - ie. it should be possible to still use those partitions regardless.

I ran out of ideas what could be wrong here - the partitions really seem to be fine! In BIOS there is some utility for flashing that allows to browse local storage, and from there I confirmed my files and directories are still there, intact, on the HDD I "recovered" from RAID manually. But then again - neither Linux nor Windows will detect them properly on the file system level...

Comment: Why are those tools referring to disk as "sda1"? Disks are usually knows as "sda", etc., and their contained partitions as "sda1", "sda2", etc. It also appears that your Disks application is looking at protective MBR and ignoring GPT. Why?

Comment: As the only "healthy" partitions are on my SSD I'm not sure how this is comparable, but it looks like disk with all partitions is recognized as /dev/nvme0n1 while particular partitions are available as /dev/nvme0n1p1, /dev/nvme0n1p2 etc.
Perhaps those tools are referring to disk as sda1 because it's an extended partition? Just a guess.

Comment: Oh, I think I see where the problem is... When moving disk content to the left, I moved the content of /dev/sda1 (which for some reason is seen as one large swap partition) instead of /dev/sda. And the fact that sda1 was containing valid partition table confused me even more. So most probably I need to shift the disk a little bit more to the left and partitions should appear in the filesystem. Will report if it helped one it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to kreemoweet's comment I was able to find out what happened.

As it turned out, I accidentally moved data of wrong block device - /dev/sda1 instead of /dev/sda. sda1 was there because for some reason linux was treating it like one big partition, thus making a block device for it. My partitions were kind of "nested" in it, so while visible in partitioning tools when used /dev/sda1 as a device to be partitioned, they obviously would not show in filesystem.

Making an additional shift (which aligned partitions tables to the real disk device) solved the problem.